# SQL Server - Compare on multiple columns in differnet rows within same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare

I have a table that holds the values read from 2 meters:

```
----------------------------
   Date   | MeterID | Value
----------------------------
  1/2/14       A       1.3
  2/2/14       A       1.8
  2/2/14       B       3.8
  3/3/14       A       1.2
  4/3/14       A       1.8
  4/3/14       B       2.9
```

I need a query that will count the number of days that a reading exists for BOTH meter types (`A` & `B`)?
In the example above this should yield 2 as the result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a temporary table to list `[Date]`s when there were occurrences in `MeterID` for both `A` and `B` and then `COUNT()` all this `[Date]`s :

```
SELECT COUNT(t.*) 
FROM ( SELECT [Date] 
       FROM [table] 
       GROUP BY [Date] 
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [MeterID]) = 2
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you for that....a further question.....If I had another field that I also wanted to filter on, for example the persons name who took the readings, then i would want to count the number of days that each person took readings of both meters on the same day - how would I add this???

Comment: @user3359779 :Well, it is not quite clear, but you can try adding `name` to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses, so you get data for each person and day.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, using sets:

```
select count(*) from
(
    select distinct date from table where meterid='A'
    intersect
    select distinct date from table where meterid='B'
) x
```